# Filter rows with the same value in a specific variable for each ID - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to exclude rows with the same value in a specific binary variable ("Y"), for each ID in the data frame.
It means that if a ID got the same values (only 0 or only 1) in Y, then it should be excluded.

Data illustration:

```
ID  X   Y
a   ..  0
a   ..  0
a   ..  0
b   ..  1
b   ..  0
b   ..  1
b   ..  0
c   ..  1
c   ..  1
c   ..  1
c   ..  1
```

Expected result:

```
ID  X   Y
b   ..  1
b   ..  0
b   ..  1
b   ..  0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `groupby()` on `ID` and `transform` as `nunique` , then filter rows with results greater than 1:

```
df[df.groupby('ID')['Y'].transform('nunique')>1]
```

---

```
  ID   X  Y
3  b  ..  1
4  b  ..  0
5  b  ..  1
6  b  ..  0
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned `filter`

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x : x['Y'].nunique()>1)
```